# Go http request falls back to http2 even when force attempt is set to false

Tags: http, go, http2

There this weird thing that keeps happening every few requests where Go's `http` package throws the following error:

```
http2: server sent GOAWAY and closed the connection; LastStreamID=19999, ErrCode=NO_ERROR, debug=""
```

And so I realised that the default transport has `ForceAttemptHTTP2` set to `true`(https://golang.org/src/net/http/transport.go line 48), so I manually set that to false like below:

```
    transport := &http.Transport{
        ForceAttemptHTTP2: false,
    }
    httpClient := &http.Client{Transport: transport}
```

But even after doing that, I still get the same http2 error instead of http1, which is not making sense to me?

I'm new to networking so I have a feeling I'm missing something that should be obvious here?

I guess the question would be how do I force the `http` package to only use `http` and not `http2`

Comment: Not forcing HTTP/2 is not the same as disabling HTTP/2.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/58088956/13860

Comment: Could you give me some more information on that? I'm not sure how I can apply that to an HTTP Client

Comment: Yeah, good point. I'm not exactly sure how to translate that to the client, either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to do it:

```
package main

import (
   "crypto/tls"
   "net/http"
)

func main() {
   client := &http.Client{
      Transport: &http.Transport{
         TLSNextProto: map[string]func(string, *tls.Conn)http.RoundTripper{},
      },
   }
   req, e := http.NewRequest("HEAD", "https://stackoverflow.com", nil)
   if e != nil {
      panic(e)
   }
   res, e := client.Do(req)
   if e != nil {
      panic(e)
   }
   println(res.Proto == "HTTP/1.1")
}
```

> Programs that must disable HTTP/2 can do so by setting `Transport.TLSNextProto`
> (for clients) or `Server.TLSNextProto` (for servers) to a non-nil, empty map.

https://golang.org/pkg/net/http#pkg-overview

Admittedly, this is pretty awkward syntax, so you might prefer something like
this instead:

```
package main

import (
   "net/http"
   "os"
)

func main() {
   os.Setenv("GODEBUG", "http2client=0")
   req, e := http.NewRequest("HEAD", "https://stackoverflow.com", nil)
   if e != nil {
      panic(e)
   }
   res, e := new(http.Client).Do(req)
   if e != nil {
      panic(e)
   }
   println(res.Proto == "HTTP/1.1")
}
```

Comment: 3rd (not less clunky) way: `go build -tags nethttpomithttp2`.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for!